# Angular Unit Testing Controller Initialization?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, karma-runner

I've looked around and can't find the answer I'm looking for, so I'll ask here. 
I'll say first off, I do suspect that this may be a case of bad practice, and if so then any advice on how best to approach this and be able to unit test would be appreciated. I'm still on the learning curve with angular (and unit testing).

It's pretty simple, I have a controller as follows, that sets a few functions on the scope, but also calls a factory for some data during it's initialization (not through a function)...

```
(function() {
'use strict';

app.controller('NavController', navController);

function navController($rootScope, $scope, $location, $window, NavFactory) {

    $scope.menuConfig = {};
    $scope.menuItems = [];
    $scope.isActive = isActive;
    $scope.toggleBurgerMenu = toggleBurgerMenu;
    $scope.toggleDeviceSettings = toggleDeviceSettings;

    NavFactory.GetMenuItems().then(onGetMenuItems, $scope.onAPIError);


    function onGetMenuItems(response) {
        $scope.moduleConfig = response.moduleConfig;
        $scope.menuItems = response.menuItems;
    }

    function isActive(viewLocation) {
        ...
    }

    function toggleBurgerMenu() {
        ...
    }

    function toggleDeviceSettings() {
        ...
    }
}
```

})();

As you can see `NavFactory.GetMenuItems().then(onGetMenuItems, $scope.onAPIError);` is called during the controller initialization. How do I test that `NavFactory.GetMenuItems()` is being called **when the controller loads**?

I thought about putting this in an `init()` function, but then to test it I would need to put `init()` on the scope wouldn't I? In order to call it from the Karma test suite? But I don't need this function to be public as it is only called from the controller.

Is there a way to test that it's being called like this? Is there a better approached?

Before anyone re-buffs me for doing it this way, it's the way I was shown on a training course, so it's the way I've learned (not saying it's right).

Ultimately, I just want to check that `$scope.moduleConfig` and `$scope.menuItems` are being set with properties and data when the controller loads.